# Calculate deduction in SQL with PHP language?

Tags: php, sql, sum

What I want: "Total number of income - Total number of expenses = Left"

I am still unable to make the code to calculate the deduction, kindly help me solve the code below, many Thank you.

```
    <?php
       include("connect-db.php");
       $left= mysql_query("Select income.inNo,expenses.eNo 
                          From income Join expenses On income.uId = expenses.uId")
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($left))
     {
       echo "Left: RM".$row['SUM(inNo)'] - $row['SUM(eNo)'];
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you need to calculate a deduction for each UID?

Comment: nope, straight away deduce the total amount of both table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT income - expense AS LEFT
FROM (SELECT SUM(inNo) AS income
      FROM income) AS i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(eNo) AS expense
            FROM expense) AS e
```

Comment: Thanks, but still getting this error: ---- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' ----
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($left))
  {

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a semicolon on the line before that.

Comment: thanks again, worked after a few changes to the name

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUM(income.inNo) AS inc, SUM(expenses.eNo) AS exp,
SUM(income.inNo) - SUM(expenses.eNo) AS Leftover  
FROM income 
JOIN expenses On income.uId = expenses.uId
```

Comment: You can't reference an alias in the same SELECT list that defines it.

Comment: Thanks, Updated it accordingly

Comment: but the sum of the amount seen to mess up, it wont total the correct amount